# TF-Serving: how to send a model version along with a response

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

**Preface**. I'm solving a classical classification task, a user sends me an image, I classify it and send him back the name of the class, additionally saving the result in a database. In order to make everything efficiently, I have a tensorflow-serving running on a machine returning a class id, as for a `{class: name}` map, it is maintained on a web server side.

Now **the problem**, *how to maintain these `{class: name}` maps in sync with TF models*? Suppose, I have a two-class classification task: `{0: "tree", 1: "car"}`. And in the second release of my model I swapped these two classes, i.e. the map became `{0: "car", 1: "tree"}` well, why not? If I hold a static mapping on a web server side, then I will classify all trees as cars and vice versa.

**Question**. What is the proper way of solving this synchronization problem?

Before you start answering, let me respond to a few pretty reasonable questions:

1. *Q*: Why can't we move this mapping to a tensorflow serving side?
   *A*: Suppose, we messed up with the naming on a tf side. Then for a while we will be writing to a DB wrong names. When we will discover that, we would need to go to a DB and rename everything. Having mapping on a web server side makes this not a problem at all. We will change this mapping and that's all, since we stored only class ids in the DB.
2. *Q*: What if a model was changed and all classes were shuffled?
   *A*: For sure, we need to version all our models and store a mapping per model.

If we take the proposed approach, then sending a model version along with the response should suffice. Can I do it in tf-serving? Other ideas and approaches how to solve this problem are welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you have some kind of service in place that wraps the TensorFlow Server and that is exposed to the user, where you could implement some extra logic.

TF Serving offers a [metadata API](https://www.tensorflow.org/serving/api_rest#model_metadata_api) (via REST or RPC), that allows you to request the SignatureDef of the model that is currently hosted. I'm not sure if this will suffice for you, as the SignatureDef might remain unchanged in the scenarios that you describe. However, the `method_name` seems to allow some [customization](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/protobuf/meta_graph.proto#L302) :

```
  // Extensible method_name information enabling third-party users to mark a
  // SignatureDef as supporting a particular method. This enables producers and
  // consumers of SignatureDefs, e.g. a model definition library and a serving
  // library to have a clear hand-off regarding the semantics of a computation.
```

Perhaps you could tie your versioning into this `method_name`, and request it each time you launch your service.